# Strange compilation error in usage of nested lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, nested, c++11

I've written some code using lambda on vc2010. The simplified structure of code is like below:

```
template<typename Functor>
bool f1(int a, Functor& f)
{
    return f(a+1);
}

template<typename Functor>
bool f2(Functor& f)
{
    return f(1);
}

template<typename Functor>
bool f3(Functor& f)
{
    return f2([&](int a) -> bool {
        // (1) Works
        auto test = [&](int b) -> bool { return f(a+b); };
        return f1(a, test);

        // (2) Doesn't work         
        //return f1(a, [&](int b) -> bool { return f(a+b); });
    });
};

int main()
{
    int a = 100;

    f3([&](int b) { return (a+b)%2 == 0; });
}
```

First I wrote a nested lambda code as (2), and vc10 gives a incomprehensible error message like below

```
'f1' : cannot convert parameter number from 'int' to 'int &'
```

However code (1) works well, which is indentical to (2) except lvalue-ness.

My question is:

1. Is code (2) conforming C++11 standard?
2. If not, what's the reason of this strange compilation behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return f1(a, [&](int b) -> bool { return f(a+b); });
```

Here, the second argument which is a lambda, is a temporary object which cannot be bound to non-const reference. I believe, the error message is misleading; it doesn't exactly tell the problem. A good compiler will print better error message. Try GCC, or Clang.

The fix is this: make the second argument non-reference:

```
template<typename Functor>
bool f1(int a, Functor f)  //I removed `&` from the second parameter
{
    return f(a+1);
}
```

Likewise, make all the `Functor` parameters in other functions non-reference. Passing functor as reference doesn't make much sense, especially in C++11, in which you can pass lambda as well which you can define on the fly.

Answer (score 4):

GCC 4.6 gives the following error:

> a.cpp: In function '`int main()`':
>   a.cpp:30:43: error: no matching function for call to '`f3(main()::<lambda(int)>)`'
>   a.cpp:30:43: note: candidate is:
>   a.cpp:14:6: note: `bool f3(Functor&)` [with `Functor` = `main()::<lambda(int)>`]
>   a.cpp:14:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '`main()::<lambda(int)>`' to '`main()::<lambda(int)>&`'

Which is clearer: your lambdas are temporaries and you are trying to bind them to l-value references. So just use r-value references or no references at all:

```
template<typename Functor>
bool f1(int a, Functor&& f)
{
    return f(a+1);
}

template<typename Functor>
bool f2(Functor&& f)
{
    return f(1);
}

template<typename Functor>
bool f3(Functor&& f)
{
    return f2([&](int a) -> bool {
        // (1) Works
        auto test = [&](int b) -> bool { return f(a+b); };
        return f1(a, test);

        // (2) Doesn't work         
        //return f1(a, [&](int b) -> bool { return f(a+b); });
    });
};

int main()
{
    int a = 100;

    f3([&](int b) { return (a+b)%2 == 0; });
}
```

No idea if VS can compile this, but GCC does it right.

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, you can not bind a temporary to a non-const reference.

There are 3 ways to fix this :

1. pass by value :

   template
   bool f1(int a, Functor f)
   {
       return f(a+1);
   }
2. pass by rvalue :

   template
   bool f1(int a, Functor&& f)
   {
       return f(a+1);
   }
3. pass by lvalue :

   template
   bool f1(int a, const Functor& f)
   {
       return f(a+1);
   }

I would go for the 3rd option (pass by the lvalue, or const reference).